# How to use the word Imagine in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english

I heard a friend saying

> “it takes an hour by a car **imagine** a bus”

Is **imagine** used correctly here?

Comment: The sentence needs some punctuation: _It takes an hour by car – imagine a bus!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example sounds like very casual conversation.
What the speaker is saying is

> It takes an hour *(to get there)* by a car, imagine *(how long it would take using)* a bus.

Quite often in casual conversation, shortcuts are taken and obvious words are left out, but the sentence in this context is correct.

Comment: Really?? Whatever happened to [_Not so fast_...](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)? (Harith, what Peter said is true, but we recommend waiting a day – or at least half a day – before you do this.)